# How do I conditionally show fields/lables using jQuery.jsForm?

Tags: jquery, jsform

I'm building a form that obtains its data from a webservice and populates using jsForm.  Everything works, but I am not sure how to go about showing a field only if it exists.  I have a list of 10 fields that only should be shown to the user if it was returned in the json response.

Any ideas for doing this?  I have scoured the documentation and think I might be able to do something with the collections feature.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled as described https://github.com/corinis/jsForm/wiki/JsForm-Dom-Layout#conditional:

```
<div class="conditional" data-show="data.active">
   this is shown only when data.active is non-null or non-false
</div>
```